# How do I change the default 'word wrap' setting in WordPad?

Tags: wordpad

(I couldn't find this anywhere on the web, so I figured I'd leave the answer here for others.)

Every time a text file opens in WordPad, I have to change the 'word wrap' setting to make it easier to read files with manual line breaks. How can I change the default setting?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (Windows 10), and might work for other settings:

Run WordPad as Administrator, then change the settings and close the app.

If this doesn't work for other settings, try: 
[Change WordPad defaults for font, type size, and line spacing](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/want-to-change-wordpad-defaults-for-font-type-size/a99d61f2-1bc7-4f98-ba98-a30acc932e16).